# After MBR2FPT New Local Disk Created

Tags: windows-10

I completed MBR2GPT and everything seems to be working well.  However, I notice that a new LOCAL DISK was created.  It contains a directory:/efi/dell/bios/recovery/bios_cur.rcv.

This disk did not exist prior to running MBR2GPT, it appeared upon reboot after the completion of the process.

Do I need to keep this disk?  If not, how do I get rid of it (I don't see it in disk manager).

This is a Dell XPS8900.

Thanks, I appreciate everyone's assistance.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot showing the appropriate amount of details would be helpful as your question is not clear making it difficult to answer your question in its current form.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: `I don't see it in disk manager` it should be there. Please show a screenshot of disk management also

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS stores logs and recovery images in esp/EFI/dell. Recovery images are stored in esp/EFI/dell/bios/recovery and are 14 MB in size. It appears that there will only be two images at the same time, BIOS_CUR.rcv and BIOS_PRE.rcv. Those files will be created when the BIOS was updated.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Latitude_3500